# Inconsistent speed animating with linear interpolation

Tags: javascript, html, math

I'm trying to animate objects around my canvas between two calculated points. However, the method I'm using doesn't seem to take into account the distance between points. For example, far distances take the same amount of time to animate as it does for short distances.

What's the best method for animating objects with a consistent speed?

```
/**
 * Update function that is called in a setInterval. Moves boid to a new position
 *
 **/
this.update = function(){
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);


    this.amount += 0.005;
    if (this.amount > 1) this.kill();

    this.x = this.origX + (this.destX - this.origX) * this.amount;
    this.y = this.origY + (this.destY - this.origY) * this.amount;

    this.drawBoid();

    //console.log(this.x + ' ' + this.y);




}
```

Comment: Your `this.amount` seems a _percentage_ value of the distance. Is it true? You're moving 0.5% percent of the distance per tick, that will of course end up with the same time however far the distance would be.

Comment: Ok, but how would maintain the speed? Would I have to calculate the distance of the two points ahead of time?

Comment: If you want to keep a consistent speed...just use a consistent speed. `this.x=this.x+speed.x`.

Comment: How would I incorporate that into animating between two set points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to take an approach where you animate based on the **time elapsed** since the last frame, and the **speed** you want to animate at, in distance-units-per-unit-time.

You have to be very careful when calculating the time elapsed; just because you scheduled `setInterval` to fire every `n` milliseconds, doesn't mean your code will fire at precisely that time. Worse, `setInterval` has a minimum delay of 4ms, no matter what. [Really](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.setTimeout#Minimum.2F_maximum_delay_and_timeout_nesting)! Instead **rely on the clock** at the time your code runs.

Better still, modern browsers have a method called `requestAnimationFrame()` that calls a chunk of code whenever a repaint is about to occur. You pass it a callback, and it calls that method with a timestamp as the first argument.

```
// Find your browser's implementation of requestAnimationFrame
window.requestAnimationFrame =
  window.requestAnimationFrame || 
  window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
  window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

// The update method
var update = function(timestamp) {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // How much time has elapsed since the start of the animation?
  var elapsedTime = timestamp - startTime;

  // How far have we moved at that time?
  var distanceTravelled = elapsedTime * speed;
  if (distanceTravelled >= totalDistance) distanceTravelled = totalDistance; // Don't overshoot

  // How far have we moved in each component?
  var distanceTravelledX = xPerUnitDistance * distanceTravelled;
  var distanceTravelledY = yPerUnitDistance * distanceTravelled;

  // Move there!
  this.x = Math.round(origin.x + distanceTravelledX);
  this.y = Math.round(origin.y + distanceTravelledY);

  // Draw!
  this.drawBoid();

  if (distanceTravelled < totalDistance) {
    // Schedule update to be called just before the next repaint
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
  }
}

// The distance you want to move
var distance = 1; // In distance units

// Speed you want to move at
var speed = 0.005 / 1000; // In distance units per millisecond

// Storage for the time when your animation started
var startTime;

// The start point, in distance units
var origin = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};

// The destination, in distance units
var destination = {
  x: 100,
  y: 75
};

// Distance to travel
var deltaX = (destination.x - origin.x);
var deltaY = (destination.y - origin.y);
var totalDistance = Math.sqrt( Math.pow(deltaX, 2) + Math.pow(deltaY, 2) );

// Storage for the contribution of each component per unit distance
var xPerUnitDistance,
    yPerUnitDistance;

if (totalDistance > 0) { 
  // Start animating!
  xPerUnitDistance = deltaX / totalDistance;
  yPerUnitDistance = deltaY / totalDistance;

  // Get the start time
  startTime = window.performance.now ?
              // Some browsers use high-precision timers
              (performance.now() + performance.timing.navigationStart) : 
              Date.now(); // A fallback for those that don't

  update(startTime);
}
```

**Update**: [Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295133/adam) pointed out that [Chrome uses a high precision timer](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/05/requestAnimationFrame-API-now-with-sub-millisecond-precision). Code has been updated.

Comment: Rq : if speed is negative, your overflow test will fail.

Comment: @VincentPiel Speed is directionless so can't/shouldn't ever be negative.  (However, velocity can be negative).

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into this. Kinematics seems fascinating; do you guys know any good beginner materials to the theory?

Comment: I really like the "The Morgan Kaufmann Series in Interactive 3D Technology" series of books.  They cover a lot of topics, including kinematics for games.  See http://www.amazon.com/Game-Engine-Design-Interactive-Technology/dp/1558605932

Comment: Is the theory of 3d and 2d the same?

Comment: 3d is slightly more general, but yes, the theory is the same.

Comment: Sorry, I tried running this code and when it calculates the x and y values I always get a single number. x is -5494715. Is there something wrong with the calculations?

Comment: I wouldn't take this code sample literally, @Adam. Just borrow the ideas from it, and adapt it to your application. When in doubt, insert a `debugger` statement or a `console.log()` to figure out what's what, when!

Comment: Ok. It turns out chrome uses a higher precision timestamp than just date.now()

Answer (score 1):

This is basic kinematics and the answer depends on what type of motion you're going for.

If you want a constant velocity, then you'll want something like this pseudo-code:

```
function moveConstantVelocity(curPos, targetPos, speed, t)
{
    /*
     * curPos - Current position of object (curPos.x, curPos.y)
     * targetPos - Destination position (targetPos.x, targetPos.y)
     * speed - Pixels-per-second to move
     * t - Seconds elapsed since previous move command
     */
    delta.x = targetPos.x - curPos.x;
    delta.y = targetPos.y - curPos.y;
    distance = sqrt(delta.x*delta.x + delta.y*delta.y);

    if (speed*t > distance)
    {
        // don't overshoot target
        newPos.x = targetPos.x;
        newPos.y = targetPos.y;
    }
    else
    {
        // Compute movement vector by normalizing delta vector
        // and then scaling it by distance traveled
        movement.x = (delta.x/distance)*speed*t;
        movement.y = (delta.y/distance)*speed*t;

        // apply movement
        newPos.x = origPos.x + movement.x;
        newPos.y = origPos.y + movement.y;
    }

    return newPos;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. If I want to implement this in a setInterval would I need to keep track of the seconds or milliseconds?

Comment: @Adam The code I provide assumes seconds as a floating-point number.  If you want "t" to be in milliseconds you'll then need to replace `speed*t` with `speed*t/1000`.